# scrollbar at the bottom using enscroll.js

Tags: jquery, scroll, scrollbar

i need your help.

you can test my code here [jsfiddle](http://goo.gl/5sFcY)

I use enscroll.js and i want to have a scroll at the bottom to view the last added line.

Comment: sorry i dont understand...it added scroll at right side...so what you want...please elaborate your quetion

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".scrollbox").scrollTop($(".scrollbox")[0].scrollHeight);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/PGuB5/84/

Comment: @Eli: I referred this fiddle. Is there any function like scrollBottom(...). Because I have a div with some rows. The dynamic contenet will prependTo this div. So it added in top position. If i am in the bottom position, i want to scroll to top record. How to do this.

Comment: Hi, i want to scroll it in the middle of page like for any particular section. is it possible? please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

It can help you to scroll end.

$('body').scrollTop($('body')[0].scrollHeight);

Comment: thank you for your help, i already try this but it does not work